# How to pass a file download selenium webdriver command through a function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written the code below to go to a particular website, select a list of values in a dropdown, and then download a file for each dropdown value using the webdriver.

There are about 15 different values that I need to pass through (ex: //option[@value='39) and download the file for each value passed through.

Is there a way to create a function of the below and then a loop to send each of the 15 values one by one through that function?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='39']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "UpdateButton"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "DownloadButton"))).click()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

For example, create a function to download the files:

```py
def download(value):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//option[@value='{value}']").click()
```

and then call the function 10 times using `range`:

```py
for i in range(1, 11):
    download(i)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, however the numbers that i need to pass are random in nature. Is there a way to send in numbers from a list.

Comment: @Stickle you can do `my_list[i]` where `i` is the index, and then accessing the list based on that index.